# Where do I place the pom.xml file?

Tags: java, android, maven

I have been going through [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuildMaven/article.html) and got maven installed, created my environment variables, created a new android project but i do not know where to place the pom.xml file ?

also, how do I run my maven build so a new .apk file is created ?

Comment: pom should be at the root folder, run `mvn3 clean install` as shown in your tutorial to create an apk file.

Comment: do i run mvn3 clean install  from dos ? if so , where to I point my dos to.. ? i mean I know i need to do a cd  to some directory.. right ?

Answer (score 3):

Maven commands that execute on a POM need to be executed in the current working directory of your project. Say your project is in `c:\myproject`. That means your pom file would be located at `c:\myproject\pom.xml`. When you run a maven command in the command line you need to set your current working directory to `c:\myproject`.

In windows if you hold down `shift` then right click on the open folder, you will see an additional menu item called `Open command window here`.

Alternatively you can always open your command window and type in `cd <path to your project>`.

Once there type in your maven commands such as `mvn3 clean install`

Heres a screenshot of the drop down for windows
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the defaul project layout:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

The pom.xml is placed in the projects root-folder.

Comment: but then how do i run a build  to create a new apk file ?

Answer (score 0):

This occurred due to change of a project name, and the old project name of a module keep showing in a bracket beside the new project name. if you want to remove the old name in the bracket[. . . .], go to your projects settings.gradle file or use short cut Ctrl+Shift+F to get the file. You will see old module project name.

- include ':app'
- rootProject.name = "the old project name of a module"

In rootProject.name="...." Renamed it with your new project name and synced the project, then the root module name will be updated and the old module project name in the bracket will be gone.